# Codeigniter Tank Auth Not Logging In?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been developing a codeigniter website for a few months now, using the Tank Auth library for users. It's still in development, but for the last 4 months everything has been working perfect.

A few days ago all of a sudden the login feature just stopped working, when you enter your credentials it just refreshes the page, regardless if you're right or wrong, and displays no error messages.

Does anyone know what is wrong? Or has anyone dealt with this before? Is there any feature I can turn on that would display any errors if they're were any. I have error reporting on and codeigniter is still set to development mode.

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide some insight to my problems.

P.s. I've searched the rest of SO, found some similar problems, but no solutions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if it's still in development then what did you change (or work on) that day when it stop working? Nothing stops from no reason.

Comment: I didn't change anything without checking. I did some ui work one night, check to make sure everything was cool, came back the next morning and couldn't log in.

Comment: ok, so did you change anything with the js, ajax, or php? maybe some facebook plugin? Check in firebug if there is some clues. You need to debug it when and where and why this happens. We can't just guess. You have to check if there is some bug in the flow of login. maybe cookie is not set, maybe sessions isn't working ok. maybe page refresh beacause of js and there is no time for setting cookie. Debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so for anyone else having this problem, which is probably slim, one of tank auth's database tables is called user_profiles, any while making my site I guess I somehow altered this. The user_id field, while a foreign key, has to be unique. Turns out the account I was logging in with had 2 different rows with the same user_id, but different primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. i checked **login_attempts** table where Tankauth stored my ip and no of login attempts. i truncate the data and everything started to work